# How to install Ubuntu 12.04 on Android 4.1 tablet?

Tags: android, tablet

How can I install and run Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an Android tablet?

I had Ubuntu installed on my laptop but its chip crashed. I want to buy a tablet and install Ubuntu 12.04 on it.

Comment: Maybe this can get you on the path: http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/